# How to use PBF file in OSM?

Tags: php, javascript, dictionary, openstreetmap

I am using OSM in my website. Now i want to use the tile images from my server/offlineI have downloaded PBF files from the following link.

[PBF Download Page](http://download.geofabrik.de/)

Now i need to point all the tiles to the downloaded pbf file in my server.How can i do that?

Comment: [Duplicate including the answer](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/25310/how-to-use-pbf-file-in-osm).

Comment: @scai: How it could be duplicate? That link is not a stackoverflow link! Are you Mad?? Or thinking that you are genius?

Comment: Not at all, I'm just pointing other users having the same problem at the solution.

Comment: @scai: Dude.. Both are posted by me only! Cool! i posted at the same time as it's an urgent for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The PBF format only includes the OSM raw data, such as coordinates, ways and relations. If you want to use it on your webserver, you have to generate the tiles from this data - that's not simple :-)